# Everytime I hover on my NavList the bottom list adds width to the top

Tags: html, css

I have the width of the first ul equal to the width of the words with margin-right = 50px and I have the bottom ul width = 200px. The problem is if the top ul width is 180px and I hover on it, the top ul matches the bottom 200px which increase the right side and pushing the list.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d60d8c;
}

.navbar-tab {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1300px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
}

.navbar-tab-1 {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.hover-list li {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  width: 200px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-tab">
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Home</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Diamond Search
      <ul class="hover-list">
        <a>
          <li>GIA Diamond Search</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>Diamonds</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Wedding Bands</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Engagement Rings</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Selection Guide</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Jewellery Services</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give absolute position to the ul element that contains submenu to prevent it from affecting the width of parent:

```
.hover-list {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d60d8c;
}

.navbar-tab {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1300px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
}

.navbar-tab-1 {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.hover-list li {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  width: 200px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.hover-list {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-tab">
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Home</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Diamond Search
      <ul class="hover-list">
        <a>
          <li>GIA Diamond Search</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>Diamonds</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Wedding Bands</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Engagement Rings</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Selection Guide</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1">Jewellery Services</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Also, I would suggest using Class selectors over tag selectors such as `ul li`, `ul li a` or `ul li ul li`. Tag selectors not-only have a slightly poor performance as compared to class selectors, but they will also apply to a larger number of elements - sometimes when you don't intend them to be - like in case you had another `ul` element in the page that listed some unrelated items.

Comment: @SangNguyen Do you mean consecutive submenus? Yes, they might, but I suppose the user won't be hovering two nav-links simultaneously. So you wouldn't see two sub-menus simultaneously.